# Why does React strip space entity at the start of a line?

Tags: reactjs

The following HTML displays a space between two characters:

```html
a
<span>
  &#32;b
</span>
```

However, trying to do it in React strips the space for some reason:

```js
ReactDOM.render((
  <div>
    a
    <span>
      &#32;b
    </span>
  </div>
), document.querySelector('.test'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Why is this happening?

Removing the line breaks inside the span resolves the issue, but prettier insists on formatting the code this way when lines gets longer. And it does not match HTML behavior on the same input.

Comment: Yeah, that's React for ya. You can also insert a `{' '}` to force a space in there.

Comment: Nope it gets stripped as well if I place it inside the span (no matter if there's a new line or not). I can place it before the span, but that would be different (if CSS hides the span, I want the space to be gone as well). `&nbsp;` does not get stripped, but it has different semantics (I definitely don't want to prevent line breaks). Ultimately I went with `&thinsp;` but it's probably slightly different from a regular space.